# Pushing messages from an Oracle database to a client

Tags: android, oracle, oracle11g, android-webservice

I am building a new Android App which has an Oracle Database as its Datasource. I already have an Soap Webservice running on an weblogic server which can accept request from the client and send back the responses generated in the database.
My Problem is that i also want to  sent Data from the database to the client without sending a request first. I already suggested long polling over the existing Webservice or the use of firebase cloud Messaging as a Solution but i would rather build my own push Provider.

My question is how to build an push Provider or if there is something else i could do to archieve my goal?